# Не понимаю в чём проблема

Tags: python, shutil

Всё правильно работает, однако `shutil.copy2(a, dir_res)` не принимает мои значения и выводит ошибку:

```
Введите директорию копирования 1:E:\CFG
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zoodlePC\Desktop\second.py", line 27, in <module>
    shutil.copytree(a, dir_res)
  File "C:\Users\zoodlePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 556, in copytree
    return _copytree(entries=entries, src=src, dst=dst, symlinks=symlinks,
  File "C:\Users\zoodlePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 457, in _copytree
    os.makedirs(dst, exist_ok=dirs_exist_ok)
  File "C:\Users\zoodlePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    head, tail = path.split(name)
  File "C:\Users\zoodlePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ntpath.py", line 185, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Вот код программы:

```
import os
import time 
import shutil

# получение имени папки:
time_s = time.time() # получение времени с начала эпохи
time_y = time.ctime(time_s) # преобразование секунд в нормальное время

# требуемые замены
time_y = time_y.replace(" ", "_") # замена недопустимых символов
time_y = time_y.replace(":", ".") #

# создание папки
directory = os.getcwd() # получаем местоположение программы
dir_res = os.mkdir(directory + "\\" + time_y) # создание папки с текущим временем

# сбор имён требуемых для архивации файлов
b = 1
i = 1
while i != 0:
    a = input("Введите директорию копирования " + str(b) + ":")
    b+=1

    if a == "Всё":
        break

    shutil.copy2(a, dir_res)
```

Comment: `os.mkdir` не возвращает строку пути создаваемой директории.

Comment: То есть путь не записывается в dir_res?

Comment: Думаю проблема в пути к новой папке dir_res, попробуйте использовать dir_res = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(directory), time_y) для корректного указания пути новой папки. B потом создавать новую папку по этому пути.

Comment: Нет, его надо где-то хранить. А еще лучше использовать более высокоуровневую `pathlib`, тогда путь никуда не потеряется, а `mkdir` будет вообще методом объекта.

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.mkdir(directory + "\\" + time_y)` возвращает None.
Присвойте переменной значение `os.path.join(os.path.abspath(directory), time_y)` и все будет работать.

Comment: Если вы про это, то: 
,,,
os.mkdir(directory + "\\" + time_y) # создание папки с текущим временем
dir_res = directory + "\\" + time_y
,,,
, то это не работает

Comment: какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: `Введите директорию копирования 1:E:\CFG
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zoodlePC\Desktop\second.py", line 28, in <module>
    shutil.copy2(a, dir_res)
  File "C:\Users\zoodlePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 434, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\zoodlePC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 254, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:\\CFG'`

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться